# Как сделать ввод значений для переменной в одну строку?

Tags: php, shell

Я пытаюсь сделать ввод значений для переменной в 1 строку, но ничего не получается

Пробовал сделать через массив - видимо руки не из того места.

```php
<?php
$n = readline();
for ($f=0; $f < $n; $f++) { 
    $i = readline();
    if ($i == 1) {
        $answer = "";
    }
}
if (isset($answer)) {
    print("HARD\n");
} else {
    print("EASY\n");
}
```

Ожидания:

```
3
0 0 1
HARD
```

Реальность:

```
3
0
0
1
HARD
```

Comment: 1. Зачем вы вводите одно число, когда хотите ввести все в одной строке? 2. Зачем вы делаете n запросов, хотя хотите сделать только один?

Comment: я это прекрасно понимаю,я создал вопрос потому что не могу понять как решить эту задачу и написал как вообще должно всё выглядить.

Comment: Вы описание `readline()` вообще читали? "Читает одну строку, введенную пользователем." Признаком конца строки является нажатие <Enter>. На экране в консоли это отражается именно переводом строки. Так как же Вы можете ожидать от неё "0 0 1", если строку клавишей <Enter> переводите после каждой цыфирки?..